# ComboBoxCellEditor only setting value on focus lost

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface

Is there a way to set the value in a `ComboBoxCellEditor` other then when the focus is lost on the cell? I'm using it in each cell of a column in a `TreeViewer` and the only time that the `setValue` method is called is when focus is lost on the cell. So when a user makes a selection and doesn't click off of the cell the value is never set to the new selection.  I've tried adding listeners on the `ComboBoxCellEditor` and on the control of the `ComboBoxCellEditor` but nothing seems to pick up the selection event.

Comment: Adding a selection listener to the CCombo/Combo control should work. Please edit your question to include the relevant code passages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that I needed to cast the control to a CCombo in order to add the correct type of listener to the ComboBoxCellEditor. Here's what I did:

```
CCombo combo = (CCombo) cellEditor.getControl();

combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener()
{

    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent paramSelectionEvent)
    {
        //selection code here...
    }

    @Override
    public void
        widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent paramSelectionEvent)
    {
        //do nothing here...
    }
});
```